# Element jumps when using jQuery slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, first **#metext_hiddentext** is hidden until you press **#btn_more_metext** and then **height: 50%** will be overwritten by **height: auto**.

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#metext_hiddentext').hide();
        $('#btn_more_metext').click(function(){
            $('#me').css( "height", "auto" );
            $('#metext_hiddentext').slideToggle('slow');
        });
    });
</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="me">
    <div id="me_content">
     <div id="meimg"></div>
     <div class="metext">
      <h1>I'm Lazor Zombie</h1>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
      <div id="metext_hiddentext">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
     </div>
     <div id="btn_more_metext">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#me {
    background: #ff8400;
    height: 50%;
}


#btn_more_metext { 
    font: 20px/10px "Rosario", 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 80px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 22px;

}
```

Comment: Well, it can be seen it title, but question is that how to remove unintentional jump effect. But I got answer already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give `padding:0` and `margin:0` or Add custom margin and padding to `<h2>` because they have default margins and that is causing jump behavior in your `slideToggle()`.

```
h2{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

[**Here is the demo having `<h2>` tag with custom margin and padding**](http://jsfiddle.net/UygmQ/1/)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is, that when div is animated, it has `overflow:hidden;`
And the h2 has some margin on it...
so try to remove margin form h2 and add it on the div that is toggeld:

here the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qk8nq/

```
#me {
    background: #ff8400;
    height: 50%;
}
#metext_hiddentext {
    margin:1em 0;
}

#btn_more_metext { 
    font: 20px/10px "Rosario", 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 80px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 22px;

}
h2 {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this can be fixed by adding `position: relative` to the container (in this case the one with the class of "metext"). But I have no idea why.